# How to create a progress bar connected to paypal in jQuery or other platform

Tags: jquery, html, css, progress-bar

I want to create a progress bar for a donation campaign. 
I would like to connect it live to the paypal account, in such a way that at every donation,payment the percentage on the progress bar would change. 
For example : if the amount of the campaign is set to 100$ , and a donor donates 10$ to the campaign the progress bar would only show 10% reached of 100%.
I tried to do one with jQuery but i failed. Maybe because i'm not good at all at programming :) 
I searched for some examples in google, forums but i didnt find something useful . 
Please help me , you are my last hope.

Comment: hire a programmer ? Otherwise post what you tried here might be better...

Answer (score -1):

```
<style>#progress-container {display:block; width:200px; height:40px; overflow:hidden;​}#progress {height:50px; width:0%; background:green;}</style>

​$(document).ready(function(){

    $('body').on('click','#update', function(){
    var progress = $('#progress').width();
    var completed_value = $('#completed').val();
    $('#progress').width(completed_value+"%");               
    });

});​

​<div id="progress-container">
<div id="progress"></div>
</div>
<input id="completed" type="text"><button id="update">Update</button>
```

​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Thx for your answer mate .... but it is not what i needed.              I intended something like this ... http://s020.radikal.ru/i714/1301/dc/67d5f611353c.jpg    ... You know, i needed a progress bar, or lets say a meter that will track the campaign progress manualy in such a way that the percentage will be updated by the administrator manualy or automaticaly by being conected and updated automaticaly from the paypal account.